# How to properly declare a typescript global type of a given module for ts-check?

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

Image that I've a module Xpto with the definition file:

```
// node_modules/@types/xpto.d.ts
export interface Vertx {
  createHttpServer(handler: () => void) : void;
}
```

And declare a helper to track my globals:

```
// runtime.d.ts
import {Xpto} from 'xpto';

declare const xpto: Xpto;
```

And finally on a JS file I have:

```
/// <reference path="runtime.d.ts" />
// @ts-check

xpto.createHttpServer(function (req) { ... });
```

For some reason I get an error on vscode: `Cannot find name "xpto"` but will work if i import the type:

```
import {xpto} from "runtime"
```

However this will generate broken code as there is no real runtime module it was just a way to me to declare which variables are available in the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `import` and `export` make the `d.ts` file into a module declaration. That is why the global versions does not work but the version with `import` does.

Try explicitly declaring `xpto` as a global using `declare global`:

```
import {Xpto} from 'xpto';

declare global { 
    declare const xpto: Xpto;
}
```